# записать в имени новой переменной значение другой

Tags: php, while

надо при каждом запуске цыкла создавать переменную с именем $row_ready_(и в этом месте значение переменной $i_i_i) пробовал сделать так:

```
while ($i_i_i < count($rand_t)) {
    function select_from_rand($i_i_i ){
        $result_ready = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `tables_list` WHERE `ip_t` = '$rand_t[$iii]'");
        $row_ready_$i_i_i = $result_ready->fetch_assoc();
        $i_i_i++;

    }
}
```

но не получаеться.. есть способ ето сделать?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем вы описание функции поместили в тело цикла?

Answer (score 1):

Подход к решению задачи неправильный. Если ряд переменных принадлежат к одному типу необходимо использовать массив `$row_ready[$ i_i_i]`, им проще оперировать, в качестве примера можно узнать количество. Во-вторых можно собрать все свойства влияющих на выборку (т.е. значение `$iii`) в один mysql запрос, вместо запросов на каждой итерации цикла, это не только в разы ускорит работу скрипта, но и даст возможность результат сразу вивисти в массив. В-третьих стоит больше внимания уделить именованию переменных.